# how to build a static library properly?

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile, cmake

I use log4cxx logging library. I need to link with its static version to avoid additional binary dependencies. I use it in my dynamic library. Default build of log4cxx produces static library but I cannot link with it because it was compiled w/o -fPIC flag. So I changed log4cxx bulding as:

```
CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -static" ./configure
make
```

As a result I received a `liblog4cxx.a` that I can link with my .so library. Linking was done by Cmake, something like:

```
target_link_libraries(my_dynamic_lib log4cxx)
link_directories(relative_path_to_dir_where_liblog4cxx.a_lives)
```

Everything looked fine until runtime. I cannot load my_dynamic_lib.so because of `undefined symbol "logger"`

Please explain me what's wrong and how to resolve this problem.

thanks

Comment: Hi, 
Are you sure library liblog4cxx.a has logger symbol defined? I don't know what OS you are using, but if you use Linux try this command to check if the problem is in this library or somewhere else:

nm liblog4cxx.a | grep "logger"

This should output the symbols defined on that library that have logger on its name. Check if logger is defined and the symbol type (should not be U -> undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify whether the shared library contains the symbol by using

```
nm -g my_dynamic_lib.so | grep logger
```

If it is shown with symbol type `U` it means it's undefined.

Normally a shared library will not resolve all the symbols it needs until run-time, so it is possible (and perfectly normal) to link a shared library with missing symbols.

If you put `-llog4cxx` at the start of the linker command line for `my_dynamic_lib.so` then it won't link to any of the code in there, and will leave the `logger` symbol unresolved until run-time.  To force it to use the symbols in the static library make sure you list the static library *after* the objects that need it:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o my_dynamic_lib.so obj1.o obj2.o -llog4cxx ...
```

I don't know how to do that with cmake, but it looks as though your CMakefile only links to `log4cxx` when linking the main executable, not the dynamic library.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would link liblog4cxx.a with your executable and not with your my_dynamic_lib.so. I don't think you can link like in your example unless you can provide documentation that says otherwise.